# Flyout Top Navigation SharePoint 2010

Tags: navigation, top-link-bar

I am working with SharePoint 2010. My site has publishing feature enabled. I am struggling with top navigation menu. My requirement is a top navigation menu with sub levels up to 4 levels at least and it should remain same through out the site and its sub sites.

I tried playing with "Navigation" options. But not able to achieve the desired result.

Please help. Many thanks

Regards
Vivek B

Comment: have u tried this site http://chrisstahl.wordpress.com/2011/01/26/customizing-sharepoint-2010-global-navigation-with-css-and-jquery-%E2%80%93-part-iii/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This menu is in charge of your navigation usually, and the attribute MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels is the one handling flyouts. According to your statement, it should work by setting to at least 4
 "
          UseSimpleRendering="true"
          UseSeparateCss="false"
          Orientation="Horizontal"
          StaticDisplayLevels="2"
          MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="1"
          SkipLinkText=""
          CssClass="s4-tn"/>

Did u tried that already? Also very important because you are using Publishing is to go in Site Settings Navigation and enable Show Subsites in the Global Navigation!!

Comment: First thanks for the reply C.Marius. Yes I have set my dynamic level to 4 and "Show Pages" and "Show Subsites" options are checked. Now I have sub sites coming as sub menus but the pages under sub sites are not coming in the dynamic menu. Any thoughts?

Comment: Pages are all published (approved)? On the Provider there is also a parameter called DynamicChildLimit which controls how many maximum levels, find it in the web.config for your web application. Also, you need to ensure same settings to show Pages and subsites on all subsites too.

Comment: Ahh my pages were not checked in. I did and now all works fine. Thanks a lot C.Marius. Just one thing can I add my pages under any list like "Pages" "Site Pages" or any other?

Comment: Also can we do any grouping in dynamic menu??? Like I want a group headers in dynamic menu and pages under a group ans so on?

Comment: Unfortunately no. The ASP.NET menu is not really that powerfull.